# Change the password for group of users by single command

Tags: command-line, bash, password

I'm looking for changing the password for a group of users with a single command. I tried the following command, which I believe that should work for me unless I missed something:

```
for i in {user1, user2,..}; do echo {new password}; passwd --stdin \; done
```

but unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
-su: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
```

Could someone correct me and let me now where is the mistake in my command?

Comment: If you want to set "OnePassword" as password to multiple users: (as root) `for i in foo bar; do echo "$i:OnePassword" | chpasswd; done` or if you want to set multiple passwords to multiple users: (as root) `for i in foo bar; do read -p "Set password for $i: " pwd; echo "$i:$pwd" | sudo chpasswd; done`

Comment: Yes, it works for me, although that was a different format - but it's working just fine 

thank you BestOfCaerbannog